# .exe file doesn't work when moved to another computer

Tags: .net, exe, emgucv

I have made image processing software on Microsoft Visual C# 2010 and it works very well.  The software uses EMGU CV image processing libraries, so I have put the .dll files along with a video and a picture inside a file on my computer. Everything still works well.

But when I transfer the same file, which contains the .exe and .dll and video and picture, to another computer, it doesn't work. My doubts are about the .net framework on the other computer. I'm sure .net is there but I'm not sure about the version.  The version on my own computer is 4.5.

Is the only problem the .net framework? Or might there be another problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your problem is very likely the .NET framework. Visual Studio.NET 2010 uses the .NET framework 4.0, not 4.5. So, your PC must have 4.0 on it, even if it isn't noticable. Also, what is wrong? What errors are occurring when you run the executable?

Comment: @mohammedmarwan: Upload the file executable to File Dropper so I download it and can see what happens. Also, if you woudn't mind, put the source on Pastebin.

Comment: I cannot post the code because some parts of it belongs to my professor, sorry. i have installed the same version of .net framework 4.5. but still doesn't work :( .

Comment: however, just now an error message came saying " assemplyinfo.exe stopped working "

Comment: It should be the .NET franework 4.0, not 4.5. Also, just upload the exe without source code.

Comment: yes the pc has .net framework 4.0 as well. Okay may I have your personal e-mail to send the exe file to you? i cannot upload it to public because it belongs to my professor as well.

Comment: @mohammedmarwan: Can you wait a few hours? I am kind of busy right now.

Comment: take your time dear, just can you provide me with your personal e-mail?